# Goldbach's weak conjecture in java

Tags: java, math, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to write a code for the [**Goldbach's weak conjecture**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture#:%7E:text=In%202013%2C%20Harald%20Helfgott%20published,in%20a%20peer%2Dreviewed%20journal.&text=Every%20odd%20number%20greater%20than%207%20can%20be%20expressed,sum%20of%20three%20odd%20primes.), which states that every odd number greater than 5 can be expressed as the sum of three prime numbers.
I have to print the first three prime numbers that are equal to the given number.
this program works but i get Time Limit Exceeded.
5 < N < 10^18

```
public static void FindPrimes(int n){
    boolean found = false;
    if(n%2 == 1 && n > 5){
        for(int i=n; i>=2; i--){
            for(int j=i; j>=2; j--){
                for(int k=j; k>=2; k--){
                    if(NumberIsPrime(i) && NumberIsPrime(j) && NumberIsPrime(k)){
                        if(i + j + k == n){
                            System.out.println(k+" "+j+" "+i);
                            found = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            System.out.println(-1);
        }
    }
}
public static boolean NumberIsPrime(int x){
    if (x == 0 || x == 1){
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= x; ++i){
        if (x % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could consider storing the values you've already calculated to be primes.

Comment: [This](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/Goldbach.java.html) might be interesting.

Comment: you can use [Sieve of Eratostene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find the primes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few improvements that could be made.  I am certain there are more that I haven't considered.

- First, try to memoize(save the primes) as they are calculated in a `Set` to better control and speed up verifying a number is a prime.
- Use the set of primes as divisors to find other primes.  They will need to iterated in a ascending order to do this so a `SortedSet` implementation would be required.
- I would check the sums of the candidates first.  If they don't add up to `n` then no need to check if they are prime.
- You can reduce your nested loops to two by finding primes `a` and `b` and then seeing if `n-(a+b)` is a prime.
- Check this site for better algorithims for finding primes.  There are many that have been presented as answers.